# Words with a letter sound at the start but not the letter

Tags: word, letters

Here is a fun little word puzzle.  The task, for as many letters of the alphabet as possible, is to find words that have the sound of the name of a letter at the start but which don’t start with that letter.  To give one example, “euphemism” starts with the sound of the name of the letter U but starts with an E.

Comment: This seems more like a game than a puzzle - it doesn't have a single solution, but it's a game of getting as many as you can. And there are several ambiguities: What counts as a word, exactly? (Does "double-u" count? "ctenophore"?) How can you tell when a word starts with the correct sound - what dialect do you use? What about if there are multiple common pronunciations, or one less common one (e.g. "ctenophore" again: it can start `/tɛn-/`, `/tɪn-/`, or `/tin-/`)?

Comment: Are computer solutions allowed?

Comment: @Tacoタコス yes if you can work out to do it but do label it as a computer solution.

Comment: @Anush most free APIs have limits between 2,000 and 10,000 requests per day. YAWL alone is 1,000,000 words (almost), and I don't feel like paying $500 to get the pronunciations today. Instead, I'll gather them over time. For now, a [tag:no-computers] answer will suffice for me. Fun puzzle! +1

Comment: Now do it in German ;-)

Comment: @HaukeReddmann please feel free to add an answer for German. They will close any new question I pose I suspect

Comment: @Anush: Actually basis of a few German jokes...about German dialects. :-)§ Arguably, any word on "Q" will do since the letter is *not* pronounced "kwu" but "ku" (as in "queue"). I also wouldn't allow learn words ("j"->"dj", "y"->"j"). §Using the "inverse" of the joke, I suggest any "pf" words like "Pferd". Almost anyone will drop the p and speak it with a simple "f" sound.

Comment: Also "v" like in "Vater" will essentially be a "f" sound. (This is a very similar sound and still a far cry compared to the English examples...)

Comment: Do hyphenated words or word pairs count?

Comment: @Taco no but feel free to add a different category of answer.

Comment: Take the names of letters: eff, aich, ell, em, en, cue, ar, ess, double-u, eks, wy.  From https://englishlessonsbrighton.co.uk/names-letters-english-alphabet/

Answer (score 9):

I was able to establish <s>4,</s> 5 numbers and <s>17, 19</s> 20 letters to meet your criteria. <sub>[1]</sub>

<sub>***Note**: This is my [no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers) answer; I'll try again at a later date for a computer powered answer driven by [WordsApi](https://www.wordsapi.com/) and [YAWL](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elasticdog/yawl/master/yawl-0.3.2.03/word.list).*</sub>

---

##### Numbers

> 1: won
> 2: too
> 4: forum
> 6: sics
> 8: ate

##### Letters

> A: eighty
>  C: seal
>  E: aeon
>  F: effort
>  G: jeep
>  H: aitch
>  I: aye
>  J: gaol
>  K: canine
>  L: elm
>  M: important, embark
>  N: inn, entrance
>  O: aubergine
>  Q: cue
>  R: art
>  S: essay
>  U: you
>  X: excel
>  Y: why
>  Z: xi

---

<sub>***1**: Special thanks to @Stiv  and @Simon Jenkins for pointing out an additional number and three more letters!*</sub>

Comment: The consonants, I grant you, are definitely harder! I'm sure there must be a 'J' word beginning with a soft 'G' though I can't think of it myself :)

Comment: PS I like the number additions here :) How about adding SICS and FORTITUDE (take your pick on 40 or 42 for that one!)?

Comment: @Stiv thanks! Though I’m on the fence with fortitude; simply because I’ve always pronounced it with a *tuh* and Google did too, so I excluded it from my answer, but I can see it, so great addition lol

Comment: @Stiv for 'J' there's 'Gaol', the alternative/obsolete spelling of 'Jail'?

Comment: The answer for N isn't right, at least in my accent.

Comment: @Anush I think anything in the realm of IN and EN would work.

Comment: I would change it to EN

Comment: T - Pterodactyl

Comment: There’s also B-bee/beekeeper, P-pea/peace, T-tea/teatowel, V-venus/video.

Comment: Also D-deal. You might even sneak in W-[double-use](https://artemest.com/products/cactus-mania-round-double-use-container) to complete your alphabet collection.

Comment: @Lawrence thanks for W! For the rest, those wouldn’t work because they start with the letter they’re intending to answer for.

Comment: I knew I missed something :D ! Glad to have helped with W - I thought that would be the toughest one.

Comment: @Stefab it would have to be pronounced tee-radactyl.

Comment: For Z, “said” in BrE sounds awfully close to “zed”.

Comment: @Lawrence only in the sense that thence and sense sound similar.

Answer (score 8):

> - A - Eight
>  - C - Seahorse
>  - F - Effect
>  - G - Jeans
>  - H - Aitch
>  - I - Eyeball
>  - K - Cater
>  - L - Elk
>  - M - Embrace
>  - N - Ensure
>  - Q - Cute
>  - R - Arson
>  - S - Escape
>  - U - Eureka
>  - X - Exciting
>  - Y - Wire

Comment: Bdellium? I am not sure how it is pronounced,.

Comment: Are there any words that start pt with the sound tee at the beginning?

Comment: @Anush 1. Bdellium is "duh-lee-uhm". 2. I don't think "pterodactyl" would count

Comment: O - aubergine, eau

Comment: @Anush it would need to be pte without a modifying trailing consonant such as r

Comment: Z - xylophone ?

Comment: @BruceWayne depending on your location "z" is pronounced "zee" or "zet", not "zai".

Comment: @infinitezero ah duh! Although I'd be really curious to find a match for the completely incorrect and totally bonkers "zed" pronunciation. :P

Comment: Z - xenophobia depending on dialect (for both Z and for xenophobia). For the other version of Z, there's an insect species called [Throscodectes xederoides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throscodectes_xederoides), but that's a stretch.

Comment: I like xederoides!

Comment: How about ptelia? Is that pronounced teelia?

Comment: @Anush I’ve deleted the suggestion because it starts with the letter it’s supposed to sound out. But as for pronunciation, I used the “Z” pronunciation from the alphabet song, where it rhymes with G, P, and V.

Answer (score 5):

> A: etude
>  C: see
>  F: effort
>  G: jeer
>  H: aitchbone
>  I: eyeglasses
>  K: cake
>  L: element
>  M: emboss
>  N: enclose
>  O: au pair
>  Q: cuticle
>  R: argon
>  S: estoppel
>  U: eustachian
>  X: exorcist
>  Y: wide
>  Z: xerography

Answer (score 1):

My attempt:

> *A*: Can [élan](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/%C3%A9lan) and [éclat](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/%C3%A9clat) be counted? As per Oxford and MW dictionary, they are pronounced as ā-ˈlän (**ay**-lan) and ā-ˈklä (**ay**-klah) respectively. However, some might argue that they are French words.  *C*: seam, seizure, seem, sick, *F*: any word starting with "ef-" e.g. effluent, *G*: jeans, *I*: any word starting with "eye". Also, [eyrie](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/eyrie). Can be pronounced as ˈaɪəri or **I**-ri. *K*: cable, *L*: any word starting with "el" e.g. elephant, elevate, *M*: any word starting with "em" e.g. embarass, *N*: any word starting with "en" e.g. entropy *Q*: any word starting with "cu" e.g. cube, cupid, *R*: any word starting with "ar". e.g. argon *S*:any word starting with "es" e.g. establish, *U*: the pronunciation of the letter forms a word - ""you"; Eucalyptus, Euphoria, <strike>Europe</strike> (excluding because in British English, it is pronounced as "your-ope". Thanks @alephzero). *X*: any word starting with "ex". e.g. exist. *Y*: Wide
> Does Pseudonym count?

Comment: I don’t think your K or O examples work.

Comment: @Anush Yeah, I noticed. Thanks for pointing it out. Is it ok?

Comment: Yes. For your last question isn’t that pronounced soo at the start?

Comment: You can't have "establish" starting with both "a" and "s"! Also Europe is not pronounced "You-rope" in British English, it is closer to "Your-ope"..

Comment: @RobPratt I have changed the entry for A but I am not sure about the words. They seem to have French origin and some might even consider them French words. I will remove the entry if I do not seem them fit in the category.

Comment: @alephzero noted. Thanks. As a non-native English speaker, I (incorrectly) pronounce Europe as "you-rope" rather than "your-ope".

Comment: @Nilay Ghosh As a *native* English speaker, I *correctly* pronounce Europe as "you-rope" rather than "your-ope" -  there is no single correct way to speak the language.